# how to make the x-axis, of a chart in a VB .net windows app, scroll instead of auto-zoom out

Tags: c#, vb.net, charts

My chart x-axis (representing time) automatically zooms out as each new point is plotted.  The earliest plot remains at the left.  (I followed the MSDN tutorial for basic chart)

But I also need to scroll to the left as each new point is plotted at the right, and specify the beginning x-axis time for the left side of chart.

x-axis:  datetime
y-axis:  function value
chart type:   line

Comment: Here's a tip. Store the data to be stored in X-axis in an array and project this array to X-axis of your chart, then start removing the first index of the array as new data comes in. this will give you a live scrolling effect

Comment: Thanks, that's a good tip!

Comment: o_O: I now assume there is no chart property for auto-zoom.  My new plan:  I will maintain a buffer of all sample points, and a buffer of data to be seen.  For each chart update, I copy the buffer of points-to-be-seen to the series. How's this sound?

Comment: Use a FIFO like [Queue(Of T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx) and just `Enqueue(new T)` and `Dequeue()`.

Comment: You can move the minimum and maximum values while adding points beyond the right border limit..

Comment: As i haven't worked on any charts yet, moreover I'm away from an actual pc to test a probable solution, i believe all u can do is, test the ideas. Using yours as mine is not Goa work for u it seems, or the ones posted by  @djv or TaW

Comment: Did you managed to solve the problem?